# Why does tensorflow put `ReadVariableOp` for some variables while doesn't put a `ReadVariableOp`s for the other?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to understand tensorBoard’s Graphs dashboard following a [tf tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs#conceptual_graph)

Here is the code

```
@tf.function
def compute_j(a, b, c):
    J = 3*(a+b*c)
    return J

# Set up logging.
stamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
logdir = 'logs/func/%s' % stamp
writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

tf.summary.trace_on(graph=True, profiler=True)

a = tf.Variable(5.0)
b = tf.Variable(3.0)
c = tf.Variable(2.0)
compute_j(a, b, c).numpy()

with writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.trace_export(
      name="my_func_trace",
      step=0,
      profiler_outdir=logdir)
```

And I got this plot

[image]

Why does tensorflow put `ReadVariableOp`s for `a` and `b`, pointed out by the red rectangles, while doesn't put a `ReadVariableOp` for `c`?